# Running OpenCV on OSx

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm very new to python.
I just installed OpenCV and I can import it from the terminal (Python > import cv2). The problem is that I can't run it on IDLE or PyCharm (module not found). I'm running python 2.7.

Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: Just to check, have you restarted IDLE and/or PyCharm? Are you sure IDLE and PyCharm are using the same version of python?

Comment: I restarted. I can open from terminal which has Python 2.7.12. IDLE is 2.7.11. I know that these are two different things, but I need to run on IDLE. If i write "idle" on terminal XQuartz opens and I get a different version (btw, import cv2 works there). I'd like to run OpenCV like I would if there was such thing as pip install cv2.